# My Ionic app can't access my local Node server from Android emulator

Tags: android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to run for the first time my React/Ionic app on an Android Emulator using Capacitor. The app should connect to my local Node server using Axios.

While my app started successfully on the emulator, all server requests failed with `Msg: Error: Network Error`

Here's the steps that I did:

- I configured Axios to connect to `http://10.0.2.2:3001` instead of `localhost`, but the requests still fail
- I opened the url `http://10.0.2.2:3001/api` in the Android Emulator Chrome browser, and it **succeeded** in connecting to my server and returning a response
- I tried adding to my capacitor.config.json file the following conf, but my app still fails

  ```
  "server": {
    "allowNavigation": ["10.0.2.2"]
  }
  ```

Would you have other advices I should try to make my app connect to my local server? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching, I found the solution in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428284/axios-post-works-in-debug-but-gives-network-error-in-android-release-build) :

- The problem comes from the fact the my app uses `http` instead of `https` requests which Android forbids by default, starting with API level 28.

To allow `http` requests, I added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to my app's `AndroidManifest.xml`

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic

Comment: I wasted two days on this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you use instances on cloud, modify host file, on linux the rute is :     /etc/hosts

add this line:

localhost < ip-public-your-instance >