# ionic capacitor android emulator can't fetch API data from local nodejs server

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, android-emulator, capacitor

I am unable to fetch any API data from my local Nodejs server using android emulator.

http:

```
url: 'http://localhost:8000/'

this.data = (await this.http.get<Res>(url + '/' + id).toPromise()).data;
```

**Will work** when fetching API as a web app.

***ionic serve***

Will **Not Work** when I run my app using android emulator.

via:
***ionic capacitor run android -l --external***

I get an Error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse:
> {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown
> Error","url":"http://localhost:8000/","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http
> failure response for http://localhost:8000/: 0 Unknown
> Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
> at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:

Comment: this question seems to be similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64847204/my-ionic-app-cant-access-my-local-node-server-from-android-emulator

Comment: my project is using capacitor. how can I implement that solution while using capacitor?

Answer (score 0):

Create a service file.

```js
export class ClassService {
  constructor(
    public httpClient: HttpClient
  ) {}

 getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<any>(`url + '/' + id`)
      
  }

}
```

Go wherever you want to call the data and call this service.

```js
 constructor(
public service: ClassService 
  ) {}
this.service.getData().subscribe(x=> console.log('Data here', x)
```